# After Effects - Keystroke to move focus to the Project Panel

Tags: after-effects, keyboard-shortcut

Is there a keystroke / keyboard shortcut to move focus to the Project Panel?

I know CMD+0 toggles Project Panel visibility, but is there a key that when pressed can be followed by UP/DOWN arrows to keyboard navigate the contents of the Project Panel.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can search for keyboard shortcuts by going to edit–>keyboard shortcuts. Searching for the project panel there only reveals the shortcut you have already mentioned. I guess that you're out of luck.

Comment: Florian I am 99% sure I found a single key that jumped focus to an already open Project Panel. Must be called something other than Show/Hide...

Comment: One way I found was to simply press cmd-0 twice, effectively closing and re-opening the project panel. Doing so puts the panel in focus.

Comment: I know. Just seems counter-intuitive to turn something OFF just to turn it ON.

Comment: That's true. Tough there is no shortcut to directly lay focus on the project-panel, so unless you're able to find some 3rd party plugin, you're stuck with this solution.